# CSS not loading properly for some users in MVC website?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, dom, cross-browser

I have developed a Asp.Net MVC application with bootstrap and CSS.
The website is not working fine for some users its layout is not showing the one as I created it.

I want the website to work same on every system and every browser.
Can anyone help??

I am sharing my Layout page html code below:

```
    @*<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">*@
    
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
    <link href="~/Content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />   -- custom stylesheet
    <script src="~/Content/js/script.js"></script>

    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/css/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/css/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
```

some screenshots on different IE versions:

With IE 10/11  -- this is the actual design
[image]

With IE 9
[image]

With IE 8
[image]

Login.cshtml

```
<div class="row mt-5">
                  <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 offset-3 bodyColor" style="border-radius: 25px;">
                      <div class="col-8 col-sm-8 offset-2">
                          <div style="max-width: 400px;">                              
                              <div class="text-center section-title">
                                  <h2>Login</h2>
                              </div>
                              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
                              <div class="input-group form-group">
                                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                      <span class="input-group-text date-Textbox"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                  </div>
                                  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "form-control textbox-font" })
                                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "textRed" })
                              </div>
                              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
                              <div class="input-group form-group">
                                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                      <span class="input-group-text date-Textbox"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                                  </div>
                                  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control textbox-font", type = "password" })
                                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "textRed" })
                              </div>
                              @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.RememberMe)
                              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RememberMe)

                              <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]" />
                              <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                  <input type="submit" value="Login" id="btnLogin" style="width:100%;" autofocus class="btn btn-main-custom" />
                                 

                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <br />
                      <br />                    
                  </div>                
                      <div class="col-sm-12 textRed text-center fontSizeLabel">
                          <p><b>(Login with Windows Username/Password)</b></p>
                      </div>                
                  <br />               
              </div>
```

Please, let me know the solution for the same....Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try to open "~/Content/css/styles.css" from the browser inspect element in the new tab to see if the application has access to this CSS file. Sometimes you have to give new file access or include the file in the project.

Comment: @AmirNaeem I am able to access styles.css file in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `<link href="~/Content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />` this before closing of `</head>` tag:

```
@*<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">*@
    
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>@ViewBag.title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          
        
        <script src="~/Content/js/script.js"></script>
    
        <link href="~/Content/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
        <link href="~/Content/css/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/css/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <link href="~/Content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />   -- custom stylesheet

        </head>
```

Comment: In IE developer tool I have changed the versions of IE to 7,8,9,10,11. but it only works fine with IE 10 and 11, below that the design has changed.

Comment: I have added some screenshots to give the idea of the issue.

Comment: It's not a CSS loading issue it's the browser compatibility issue. Some of the CSS properties are not properly supported by old browser.

Comment: Even the button click event is not firing but for others is working fine. So how can I resolve this?

Comment: Usually, it happens in old browsers It depends on the HTML layout and CSS cannot debug this without proper code.

Comment: Check the login page html layout!

Comment: It looks like a bootstrap 4 layout Sadly no support for old browser here is the browser support comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/#internet-explorer

Comment: Thanks brother.... may be I have to try bootstrap 3..

Comment: Hi @MohammadAreeb if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: issue still not resolve......